# POST parameters not received in drupal module

Tags: 7

I am sending a POST to a Drupal module. How can I receive the parameters values in the module and display?

I have tried using `$val = $_REQUEST['']`, `$_POST['']`, `$_GET['']` but it is just showing the null value.

I want to get the POST request and send the response back in JSON.

```
function module_menu(){  
  $items = array();  
  $items['page-json'] = array(  
  'title' => 'JSON Output',  
  'page callback' => 'json_page',  
  'page arguments' => array(1),  
  'access callback' => TRUE,  
);  
  return $items;  
}  
function json_page(){  
  $dt = $_REQUEST['param'];  
  return drupal_json($dt);  
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you 'sending a post to a drupal module' ? Did you create a a page with hook_menu or is it a normal drupal page?

Comment: Yes, I created a page with hook_menu.

Comment: If you write your hook_menu and your callback, we will figure it out

Comment: I have added code to the question..

Comment: did you figure it out now ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an empty string with those super global variables. You need to use a string that is the parameter you request, such as in `$_GET['q']`, or `$_REQUEST['q']`.

Comment: ...or just use $_REQUEST or $_GET to get the full array

Comment: sorry that i didn't mentioned it like $_POST['param_name']...but I am doing it like that...still not receiving the value....is there any permission I need to set in drupal....I am actually new to drupal don't know much related to it.....

Comment: @Mike: I tried $_REQUEST but its null everytime...